# Make 3D animations

Tags: 3d, animation, modeling

How can I make 3D animations? Like the Overwatch short films?
Looking for a software with decent shaders, maybe can model, and of course animate. All of this doesn't have to be in one software but I'm just looking for softwares with these things.

Comment: Try blender from blender.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best answer is [Blender 3D](https://www.blender.org/):

- it can do all that you need and more
- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Full 3-D modelling up to photo-realistic results if desired
- Animation and Rendering including moving items, lights and cameras
- Excellent Shading
- Video editing